# jQuery function to select one element of multiple ones with the same class

Tags: jquery

I want to make a function that I can re-use, that's why functions are made after all lol.Anyways, the code is as following:

```html
<div id="shot_filters">
  <a href="#" id="filter_active">
    <span class="filter_row_down"></span> By date </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="filter_row_down"></span> By likes </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="filter_row_down"></span> By views </a>
  <span class="filter_p"></span>
  <a href="#" class="tags_flip"><img src="static/img/retina/tags_icon.png" style="width: 13px; height: 14px">Tag search</a>
  <span class="filter_p"></span>
  <a href="#"><img src="static/img/retina/gallery_icon.png" style="width: 13px; height: 12px">Beauty gallery</a>
</div>
```

What I want is to make a function like that:

`function changeClass(name)`

From the multiple a hrefs and their classes I want when I click each of them to change their own CSS.For example: I click on By likes, it changes span class, adds a href id as filter_active and removes the filter_active from the other one.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should at least try to write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#shot_filters a').on('click',function(){
      $('#shot_filters a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="shot_filters">

    <a href="#" id="filter_active">
        <span class="filter_row_down"></span>
        By date    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="filter_row_down"></span>
        By likes    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span class="filter_row_down"></span>
        By views    </a>

    <span class="filter_p"></span>
    <a href="#" class="tags_flip">
        <img src="static/img/retina/tags_icon.png" style="width: 13px; height: 14px">Tag search</a>

    <span class="filter_p"></span>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="static/img/retina/gallery_icon.png" style="width: 13px; height: 12px">Beauty gallery</a>

</div>
```

Hey, you need an event on every anchor tag when user click in single a tag then you need to add active class and remove from others like this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should create individual listener for each element to be listened.

```js
$("a").each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("class1");
   });
});
```

```css
a::after{
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
.baseclass{
  cursor:pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.class1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
<a class="baseclass class1">Row : Click Me</a>
```